# ¿Cómo crear varios jar a a partir de un sólo build.xml con ant en eclipse?

Tags: java, jar, ant

Quiero crear a partir del código varios jar diciendo qué clases compile y cuales no todo declarado en un sólo build.xml para ejecutarlo y que me cree varios jar. Actualmente tengo lo siguiente:
`

```
<target name="create_run_jar" depends="buildAll">
        <mkdir dir="${DIST_DIR}" />
        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${DIST_DIR}" includes="**/*" />
        </delete>
        <mkdir dir="${DIST_DIR}" />
        <jar destfile="${DIST_DIR}/BATCH_ADT.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.rsi.adt.main.MainGenerateAlertas" />
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/bin" />
        </jar>
        </>
    </target>
    <target name="buildAll">
        <mkdir dir="${BUILD_DIR}" />
        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${BUILD_DIR}" includes="**/*" />
        </delete>
        <mkdir dir="${BUILD_DIR}" />

        <echo message="${classpath}" />

        <tstamp />
        <javac srcdir="${src}" debug="true" classpath="${classpath}" destdir="${BUILD_DIR}"> 
                        <!-- PARTE BEAN ADT-->
                        <include name="com/prueba/adt/bean/adt/Alerta.java"/>   
        </javac>
```

He probado lo siguiente leyendo la documentación crear

```
    <target name="batch_100_jar" depends="buildAll">
            <antcall target="clean"></antcall>

                    <mkdir dir="${DIST_DIR}" />
                    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                        <fileset dir="${DIST_DIR}" includes="**/*" />
                    </delete>
                    <mkdir dir="${DIST_DIR}" />
                    <jar destfile="${DIST_DIR}/BATCH_ADT_100.jar">
                        <fileset dir="${basedir}/bin" />
                                </jar>
            <javac srcdir="${src}" debug="true" classpath="${classpath}" destdir="${BUILD_DIR}"> 
                                    <!-- PARTE BEAN ADT-->

                                    <include name="com/rsi/adt/bean/adt/Alerta.java"/> 
</javac>
        </target>
```

Pero no me crea el segundo jar. No sé si puedo crear un nuevo project dentro del build.xml o siquiera si se puede crear lo que quiero.
Gracias de antemano

He conseguido que me cree 2 jar, de tanto tocar creo que el error estaba en que el project tenía name (no lo sé bien) pero me compila las mismas clases y los jar son idénticos. Intento dentro de la etiqueta javac lo siguiente (leyendo la documentación) un `includes= "${src}/ruta/claseprueba.java"` pero no me lo compila. No sé exactamente de dónde está cogiendo las clases que me compila. Pero quiero que del src, donde están todas me compile para cada jar unas determinadas

Answer (score 1):

Lo he conseguido, pero antes de nada después de empaparme por internet y de como compilar builds con ant, **queda desaconsejado crear más de un jar por build**

- En cada directiva `javac` he usado`javac includeantruntime="false"` para "limpiar" el compilador en cada paso que diera (he creado 4 jar).
- Dentro de la etiqueta de compilación he usado los .java a compilar

  `<javac includeantruntime="false"> <include name=` `"**/prueba.java"/></javac>`
- Y después ya compilado, he creado un jar y he empaquetado lo compilado añadiendo a ese jar un directorio de properties.

```
            <jar destfile="${DIST_DIR}/BATCH_1.jar">
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/bin" />
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/config_properties_batch_1">
                    <include name="*.*"/>
                </fileset>
            </jar>
```